# compile dynamic template with ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I stuck with the following case. I have dynamic template (template.html) with ng-include.

```
<div data-ng-include data-src="childTemplate">{{ var }}</div>
```

if I try to do:

```
$scope.childTemplate = 'child.html';
tpl = $compile($templateCache.get('template.html'))($scope);
```

in this case tpl contains only compiled parent template without the child template. I tried to do

```
<div data-ng-include data-src="childTemplate" onload="templateLoaded()"></div>
```

and

```
tpl = $compile($templateCache.get('template.html'))($scope);
$scope.contentLoaded = function() {
    $compile($templateCache.get('child.html'))($scope)
}
```

in this case child.html loaded but not included to parent template. How to solve the task? Thanks!

Comment: can you create plnkr for your question?

Comment: here's simple example http://plnkr.co/edit/DLJAPlqEZI2pMc0METjn?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

`tpl` is now the element compiled on your DOM.
What you should do is, after the `child.html` is compiled, to add it to your DOM.

Thus, you can do the following:

```
tpl = $compile($templateCache.get('template.html'))($scope);
$scope.contentLoaded = function() {
    var child = $compile($templateCache.get('child.html'))($scope);
    tpl.appendChild(child);
}
```

This could work if you want to add `child.html` template as the last of `tpl` children (if not, you should navigate it).

Comment: Why this answers get -1, could you explain why you give -1 to @Michael. Because he said something false or because is off the topic? or something like that, so I know why I need to refuse this answer.